# Twitter Bootstrap tabs not hiding content

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a little problem with my code. The tabs load but when I  click on another inactive tab doesn't hide the content of the first tab and displays the content of both tabs. Is there anything I can do? Thank you very much!

```
    <ul style="list-style:none"class="available-tabs nav nav-tabs" id="tabs" data-tabs="tabs">
          <li class="active"> <a data-toggle="tab" href="#featured-tab-body">FEATURED PROJECTS</a></li>
          <li> <a data-toggle="tab" href="#available-latest-tab">LATEST PROJECTS </a> </li>
 </ul>
<div class="available-content tab-content container">
  <div id="available-featured-tab">
    <div class="featured-list-wrapper">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="featured-list-content">
            <div class="row featured-tab-head" style="color:black;height:40px">
              <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-8">
                <h5> YAE</h5>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 hidden-xs">
                <h5>NAH</h5>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-2 hidden-sm hidden-xs">
                <h5>HEY</h5>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-2 hidden-xs">
                <h5>YOU</h5>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="featured-tab-body tab-pane fade in active">
              sup
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="available-latest-tab" class="tab-pane fade">
    hi
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: create demo like jsfiddle

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Th3Vampir3/xFW8t/1775/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/xFW8t/1776/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put all the div contents under the same root div.
So istead of:

```
<div class="available-content tab-content container">
    <div id="available-featured-tab">
        <div class="featured-list-wrapper">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="featured-list-content">
                        <div class="featured-tab-body tab-pane fade in active">
                            sup
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="available-latest-tab" class="tab-pane fade">
        hi
    </div>
</div>
```

You need:

```
<div class="available-content tab-content container">
    <div id="available-featured-tab">
        <div class="featured-list-wrapper">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="featured-list-content">
                        <div class="featured-tab-body tab-pane fade in active">
                            sup
                        </div>
                        <div id="available-latest-tab" class="tab-pane fade">
                            hi
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

No need for the Jquery, since bootstrap do the work for you.
Corrected fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/xFW8t/1777/